# Cron environment inconsistency

Tags: cron

I've seen some inconsistencies between the cron environment and my environment.

For example, I have installed `paver` (`pip install paver`) in my environment and calling paver works `paver`. Using paver in my cron doesn't work `command not found`. Everything is done through the same user `root`.

Any idea ?

Comment: May my question is include in the one you mention, but I thing having a narrower topic can be helpful. Thanks for the tip however!

Comment: If you open that question, and press Ctrl+F (or whatever the equal is in your browser), and type "environment" - the correct answer is the second hit on the page. Your comment is in effect saying "I can't be bothered to actually read anything; please spend your time to spoon feed me the informatin I want". That is rather rude.

Comment: I didn't say that. I did look in the question you pointed and found my answer, I just don't have the time now to edit an answer to this one. And I still think that narrow question are better indexed and easier to later look for through search engines.

Comment: @AsTeR Perhaps so, but the problem is that these questions are _very_ frequently asked. Which is why we have that question and [others like it](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/126632). It's not useful to have 5,000 identical questions and answers...

Comment: @MichaelHampton you are the moderator here. I don't agree that my question is "identical" to the one pointed, as SO is not identical to the `man`

Answer (score 1):

Just use full paths to binaries in your cron. So `paver` should be `/usr/bin/paver` (or wherever `paver` binary is).

You can find this out easily with `which` command:

```
$ which cd
/usr/bin/cd
```